# Numerical Analisys and StepDataPlot

Tags: differential-equations

I'm using StepDataPlot to compare several methods for differential equations. Does exists a function, or something else, to find the number of steps that the choosen method used to find the numerical solution of a differential system? I'm not an experto so I'm looking to a symple code, but I didn't find something interesting. Thank you for the help.
Roberto.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica!  
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Determining the time taken, using `AbsolutyeTiming`, may be more meaningful.

Comment: Tank you, but I really need to know the number of steps. I've tried with this code, but seems to be an incorrect number:
Block[{e = 0}, 
 NDSolve[Sys2, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta", 
  EvaluationMonitor :> e++]; e]

Comment: ...and you've seen `StepMonitor` already?

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you!